# Provide alternative render method for React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

In my app I have several form field components that all behave the same way but look slightly different. I want to be able to use the state and class methods of a single formfield component while providing some sort of alternative render method so that I can customize the appearance of this element on the fly. I know I can wrap children and then use the `props.children` in the component. But I'm looking to re-use the components methods somehow:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div className="parent">
      <ChildFormField
        renderAlternate={self => {
          return (
            <div className="child--alternate">
              <input onChange={self.doThing} />
            </div>
          );
        }}
      />
    </div>
  }
}

// And the child component look something like...
class ChildFormField extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: null
  }

  doThing = value => {
    return this.setState({ value });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.renderAlternate !== undefined) {
      return this.props.renderAlternate();
    }

    // standard return
    return <div />;
  }
}
```

I'm relatively new to React outside of its basic usage. Is there a recommended way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Separation of concern is the issue here, you are passing JSX from the parent to the child, here rendering your child is dependent on your parent's JSX

Answer (score 2):

Your `renderAlternate` function expects a parameter `self`. So you need to pass `this` when calling it.

```
return this.props.renderAlternate(this);
```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/w759j6pl6k as an example of your code.

Comment: Ah I didn't even think this could work. Lemme try this. Do you see any scaling or performance issues with this method if there were 50-100 nodes like this in a view?

Comment: @JLF not really, this is a pattern called [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

Answer (score 1):

This recipe is known as [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html). It's widely used where it's suitable, but here it looks like bad design decision, primarily because it exists to access component `self` instance. This is the case for inheritance:

```
class AlternateChildFormField extends ChildFormField {
  render() {
      return (
        <div className="child--alternate">
          <input onChange={this.doThing} />
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

In React, function composition is usually preferred, but inheritance is acceptable solution if it serves a good purpose. `ChildFormField` requires `doThing` to be a method and not helper function because it needs to access `this.setState`.

An alternative is to use React 16.7 hooks and functional components. This way the same component can be expressed with composition:

```
const useThingState = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ value: null });

  return value => {
    return setState({ value });
  };
}

const ChildFormField = props => {
  // not used here
  // const doThing = useThingState();

  return <div />;
}

const AlternateChildFormField =  props => {
  const doThing = useThingState();

  return (
    <div className="child--alternate">
      <input onChange={doThing} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good idea if I had many repeatable variations. But for the most part, these will need to be rendered with their variation in one-off situations.

Comment: Inheritance is fully valid for one-time use. Even though it's not favoured in React ecosystem, it's much more suitable than render prop - you already know that the component may be extended, so you can design it in DRYest way. And 16.7 hooks are suitable alternative for those who prefer FP in React realm.

Answer (score 0):

The common way this is managed in React ecosystem are High Order Components:

ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html
ref: https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/reusing-react-component-logic-with-higher-order-component-3fbe284beec9

Further, what you are looking for maybe a reuse of state logic.

As React 16.7-alpha you can use hooks to reuse state logic with functional components but APIs are subject of possible breaking changes.

ref: https://medium.com/@nicolaslopezj/reusing-logic-with-react-hooks-8e691f7352fa